# Angular 12 routing issue with slash in path

Tags: angular, routes

I've got a problem with Angular 12.2.2 application's routing. Basically it seems like for some reason I cannot use '/' in path.

If my routes definition looks like the one below everything works fine when I go to http://localhost:4200/home

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: WelcomeComponent },
]
```

But when I define it like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home/something', component: WelcomeComponent },
]
```

or

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home/:something', component: WelcomeComponent },
]
```

and go to http://localhost:4200/home/something I get blank page and following errors in browser's console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/home/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   something:1 
GET http://localhost:4200/home/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   something:1 
GET http://localhost:4200/home/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   something:1 
GET http://localhost:4200/home/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   something:1 
GET http://localhost:4200/home/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   something:1 
GET http://localhost:4200/home/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)    something:1
```

Do you have an idea what is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: make sure you have `<base href="/">` in your index.html

Comment: thanks for quick reply, just checked and I do have <base href="/"> in <head> of index.html

Comment: setting base href properly was a thing in my project, for unknown reason previous developer set it to `<base href="./">` and relative paths didn't generate well; changing base href just to `/` solved problem. Also note if you run a project in any subdirectory, you must indicate it in base href too, for example angular app under URL `https://example.com/myapp` should have `<base href="/myapp/">` (leading and following slash is for some reason mandatory)

Answer (score -1):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home/:something', component: WelcomeComponent },
]
```

in this example you need put / after : not before it

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home:/something', component: WelcomeComponent },
]
```

this is the right way to do it

Comment: according to official documentation the colon suppose to be after the slash, even though I tried and still doesn't work